# Priority of street labels over amenity icons

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik, tilemill, cartocss

OK, so I have a CartoCSS project.

These are all of the stylesheets used (as described in my **project.mml**):

```
  "Stylesheet": [
    "palette.mss", 
    "base.mss", 
    "roads.mss", 
    "labels.mss",
    "extras.mss"
  ],
```

In the **labels.mss** file, I'm styling the labels. Here's the part I'm interested in:

```
#minorroad_label[zoom>15] {
  text-name:'[name]';
  text-face-name:@sans;
  text-placement:line;
  text-size:9;
  text-fill:@street_text;
  text-halo-fill:@road_halo;
  text-halo-radius:1;
  text-min-distance:60;
  text-size:11;
  text-allow-overlap: false;
}

#minorroad_label[oneway!=0][zoom>=16]{
  marker-placement:line;
  marker-height:1;
  marker-fill: #bbb;
  marker-line-opacity:0;
  marker-spacing: 250;
}

/* ================================================================== */
/* ONE-WAY ARROWS
/* ================================================================== */
#motorway_label[zoom>=16],
#mainroad_label[zoom>=16],
#minorroad_label[zoom>=16] {
  [oneway = 'yes'],
  [oneway='-1'] {
     marker-placement:line;
     marker-max-error: 0.5;
     marker-spacing: 200;
     marker-file: url(img/oneway.svg);
     marker-fill: white;
     [oneway='-1'] { marker-file: url(img/oneway-reverse.svg); }
     [zoom=16] { marker-transform: "scale(0.5)"; }
     [zoom=17] { marker-transform: "scale(0.75)"; }
  }
}
```

In the **extras.mss** file, I'm setting up the amenity icons. Here's an example:

```
.points { 

    ::amenity {

        [amenity = 'arts_centre'][zoom >=17] {
            marker-transform: scale(@icon_scale); 
            marker-placement: interior; 
            marker-fill: @icon_fill;
            marker-file: url('icons/shop/art.svg');
        }

        [amenity = 'atm'][zoom >=17] {
            marker-transform: scale(@icon_scale); marker-placement: interior; marker-fill: @icon_fill;
            marker-file: url('icons/atm.svg');
        }

        //[amenity = 'bank'][zoom >=17] {
        //  marker-placement: interior; marker-fill: @icon_fill;
        //  marker-file: url('icons/bank.svg');
        //}

        [amenity = 'bar'][zoom >= 17] {
            marker-transform: scale(@icon_scale); marker-placement: interior; marker-fill: @icon_fill;
            marker-file: url('icons/bar.svg');
        }

        [amenity = 'biergarten'][zoom >= 17] {
            marker-transform: scale(@icon_scale); marker-placement: interior; marker-fill: @icon_fill;
            marker-file: url('icons/biergarten.svg');
        }

        [amenity = 'cafe'][zoom >= 17] {
            marker-transform: scale(@icon_scale); marker-placement: interior; marker-fill: @icon_fill;
            marker-file: url('icons/cafe.svg');
        }

        [amenity = 'pub'][zoom >= 17] {
            marker-transform: scale(@icon_scale); marker-placement: interior; marker-fill: @icon_fill;
            marker-file: url('icons/pub.svg');
        }

        [amenity = 'restaurant'][zoom >= 17],
        [amenity = 'food_court'][zoom >= 17] {
            marker-transform: scale(@icon_scale); marker-placement: interior; marker-fill: @icon_fill;
            marker-file: url('icons/restaurant.svg');
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, in places where there are a lot of cafes or restaurants for example, all I can see the related icons -- with the street names, nowhere to be found.

**What it looks like with the above code**

[image]

**What it looks like if I remove the icons altogether**

[image]

**What I want to do is:** make the street names appear no matter what, and IF there is enough space for the icons, then that's fine. But the street names (`#minorroad_label` namely) should have *priority over* the icons.

I've tried moving things around, changing the order of the stylesheets, putting the icons' part before the labels, or after the labels, as if it'd affect the priority, but to no avail. I've also played with `text-allow-overlap` and `marker-allow-overlap`. Well, setting them to `true` does make them appear, but then it's a mess; definitely not what I want.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

For all of you who may come across this question, here's how I resolved:

I just changed the sequence of the layers in the `project.mml` file, by putting the labels' related ones first.

*(Yep, I had moved things around a lot in almost all files, except for the right one)*